# TFF: How split data of each client

Tags: tensorflow-federated

Why in the federated learning task, we don't split our dataset to train, test and validation, we make only train and test .

Answer (score 3):

The choice of how to split the datasets is really up to the evaluator and what they are trying to accomplish. The preprocessed datasets in TFF (from `tff.simulation.datasets`) are usually only split into two, but they can be rejoined and split again in whatever way is desired.

One thing to consider: there are (at least) two dimensions that may be interesting to split on for federated learning.

1. *examples*: Splitting a single client's dataset into train, test, and validation. This could possibly be seen as most analogous to the centralized training regime. Most TFF datasets use this.
2. *users*: Splitting users into train, test, and heldout *users* might be particularly interesting in the federated regime. This might be able to answer how well a global model generalizes to *unseen* users, but might be heavily affected by the non-iid ness of the individual datasets and splits. This is used in a few TFF provided datasets.

Furthermore, both of these could be time based (if there is a notion of time), for example splitting each clients dataset into "previous day" (train) and "next day" (test). Or, as is often the case in practice with cross-device FL, splitting by time of day (users available for training at night maybe different than mid-day), [Eichner 2019](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.10120) performed some experiments using this setup.

**Note**: the [`tff.simulation.datasets.stackoverflow.load_data`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/simulation/datasets/stackoverflow/load_data) does have three splits named `train`, `held_out` and `test`. Please read the documentation carefully as it utilizes both types of splitting mentioned above.